# Http 404 error,The resource cannot be found error MVC Framework, Views : Logged/LogInfo,Logged/LoggedIn

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Receiving 404 error when accessing localhost:64803/Logged/Login
Here is the RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(

            name: "LogginInfo",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Logged", action = "Loginfo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );
    }
```

Controller:
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LogInfo customer)
        {
            var user = _Context.LogInfos.Where(c => c.UserName == customer.UserName && c.PassWord == customer.PassWord);

```
        if(user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserName"] = customer.UserName;
            return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
        }
    }
    public ActionResult LoggedIn(int id)
    {
        var usr = _Context.LogInfos.Where(c => c.id == id);
        if (Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(usr);
        }
```

Comment: you need to add more context to this question. What is the url that is causing the error?

Comment: The Url is http://localhost:64803/Logged/Login

Comment: The "LogginInfo" route shouldn't be necessary. Make sure your Login and LoggedIn actions are in a controller name `LoggedController`. To go to ~/Logged/Login you also need a `[HttpGet]` Login action (this is default if you don't use an attribute on the action).

Comment: try  localhost:64803/Login/LoggedIn/1

Comment: Thank you that worked , I completely forgot about the [HttpGet]

Comment: Optionally, comment out Default route registration as it is same as the one you've added already. Change the redirect statement to RedirectToAction("LoggedIn", "Logged");